# Error on Android studio for opening a project

Tags: android, performance, android-studio

I am trying to open an Android Studio News App project but getting this error agian and again i.e. 
**Project :News-Android-App declares a dependency from configuration 'implementation' to configuration 'default' which is not declared in the descriptor for project :MaterialShowcaseView:library.**

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the configuration for your dependency. If you don't, it assumes a "default" configuration, which will give you an error. The MaterialShowcaseView Library has a GitHub page and they give you the directions for how to add to Gradle.  The link is 
https://github.com/deano2390/MaterialShowcaseView
Since you didn't provide any details, I don't know if you already tried this. But the error indicates that you must have failed to add something in the gradle files.
[here's a screen shot of the gradle directions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e69Cm.png)

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/09Wnk.png Please help me after seeing this , I am still on the same stage. Could not make project. Thanks in advance

Comment: This line: compile 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.2.0' should be in the dependency area of your app level gradle.build, not the project level.  You have this line in the wrong gradle file in your project level gradle file, that's the wrong one.

Comment: The app level gradle.build file will look somewhat like this:

    apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.2"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 11
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.github.deano2390:MaterialShowcaseView:1.2.0'
}

Comment: And sorry for the poor formattng, couldn't get it to add as a snippet!